# StackOverFlow RSS Feed Failing

Tags: rss, stack-overflow

I'm using RSSOwl and the below feed fails as "Invalid or Malformed Feed".

https://stackoverflow.com/feeds/tag?tagnames=robotframework&sort=newest

When I put the feed url into 'Feed Validator' it identifies a number of errors.

http://feedvalidator.org/check.cgi?url=http%3A%2F%2Fstackoverflow.com%2Ffeeds%2Ftag%3Ftagnames%3Drobotframework%26sort%3Dnewest

Has anyone else encountered this?  How would I open a ticket with StackOverflow?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, I also got an error message:

> An invalid XML character (Unicode: 0xf) was found in the element
>   content of the document

You can add a new question about this to [meta.stackoverflow.com](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/bug/info) with a [bug tag](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/?tab=bugs)

Comment: Ok. Thanks for verifying and how to proceed with reporting.  I'll add a question over in meta.

Comment: Please, share the link here too if you can!

Comment: Here's the link http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/288597/stack-overflow-rss-feed-failure?noredirect=1#comment168489_288597